# Conditional Max/Min on Horizontally oriented data

Tags: excel

[Example data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtQeZ.png)

Right, above is a link to an image of a sub-segment of my data set. It is oriented in sets of 3 columns, with the first being a concentration, the second a qualifier, and the last an MDL - and continues for up to 95 samples (so a total of 285 columns making manual entry impractical) . How can i calculate the max or min of the concentration values for those that have a qualifier of "u" or vice versa have no qualifier?

I can't figure out anything, and unfortunately i don't have the time to re-orient the data. Anybody have an idea?

Comment: See [Why Not Images of Code and Sample Data](http://tinyurl.com/kdxb7le) and [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).

Comment: What do you mean by max or min of the concentration values? Do you only have 1 row of data?

Comment: No, the selected screen shot was only an example. What i have is 167 rows (analytes i am looking at like Mercury, lead etc), and up to 235 columns of data. Columns are grouped into sets of 3. Every 1st column is a concentration, and every second column is a qualifier (either blank, u, or j). What i want is a max of all concentrations that don't have a J for  a particular analyte.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like this will do,

[image]

The 8 formulas in C7:J7 are,

```
=AGGREGATE(15, 6, $A2:$AY2/(($A$1:$AY$1=C$6)*($B2:$Z2="U")), 1)
=AGGREGATE(15, 6, $C2:$BA2/(($C$1:$BA$1=D$6)*($B2:$AZ2="U")), 1)
=AGGREGATE(14, 6, $A2:$AY2/(($A$1:$AY$1=E$6)*($B2:$Z2="U")), 1)
=AGGREGATE(14, 6, $C2:$BA2/(($C$1:$BA$1=F$6)*($B2:$AZ2="U")), 1)
=AGGREGATE(15, 6, $A2:$AY2/(($A$1:$AY$1=G$6)*($B2:$Z2<>"U")), 1)
=AGGREGATE(15, 6, $C2:$BA2/(($C$1:$BA$1=H$6)*($B2:$AZ2<>"U")), 1)
=AGGREGATE(14, 6, $A2:$AY2/(($A$1:$AY$1=I$6)*($B2:$Z2<>"U")), 1)
=AGGREGATE(14, 6, $C2:$BA2/(($C$1:$BA$1=J$6)*($B2:$AZ2<>"U")), 1)
```

Those cover both minimum and maximum values when either including or excluding the qualifier.

**[Addendum: Excluding blank cells](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF)**

One more condition to check the [LEN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/len-lenb-functions-6a149d3a-ba2e-4394-ad47-2eb083265a56) of the values can be added. To change the length of the value into a divide-by-1 (unchanged) or divide-by-0 (#DIV/)! error) wrap the LEN in the [SIGN function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SIGN-function-cfaaf798-9b34-4569-955c-a74a523a7c4a).

```
=AGGREGATE(15, 6, $A2:$AY2/(SIGN(LEN($A2:$AY2))*($A$1:$AY$1=C$6)*($B2:$Z2="U")), 1)
```

I'm retaining the [SMALL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SMALL-function-4050a82e-659a-4ef6-a970-c963a6f69c29) sub-function as only AGGREGATE's sub-functions 14 and up process as an array.

Comment: I get what you did here. :) it took a second.

Comment: There were too many questions like this today and I was cranky. :P~

Comment: That is awesome! I completely forgot about aggregate as an option, but even if i had remembered i wouldn't have known how to tweak it to accept only certain qualifier values like you did. Can't thank you enough man, you just saved me a whole lot of work!

Comment: Alright, so here is a followup question; you have any idea how to get the formula to omit an empty set of cells? For instance, if Columns D-F are all blank, it will calculate the "MIN not U" as 0; because it reads the empty cell as a 0 value. I don't see any of the "options" helping me in the aggregate function . I am trying to figure out a work around, but wasn't sure if you might already know. <The joys of trying to clean up a dataset....>

Comment: Add a check for the [LEN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/len-lenb-functions-6a149d3a-ba2e-4394-ad47-2eb083265a56).

Comment: Thanks for editing the answer! It all works perfectly. 

I am still working to parse out the format you have for various conditions. I get to what each part refers to; but i am still trying to get what the actual function does when it comes do "dividing" row 2 by the product of the conditions. Its a nice and straightforward solution; just the first time i have seen that.

Comment: The AGGREGATE function has the ability to disregard errors. By dividing any entry we do not want by zero, the number becomes a `#DIV/0!` error and is not part of the result set. Anything FALSE is considered zero and anything TRUE is considered one. If all the conidtions match then we divide by 1 (no change); if any conditions do not match them we divide by 0 (error, discarded).