# Conditional Horizontal Count of Data in Excel

Tags: database, excel, excel-formula

[image: Lab Example]I have been working on a large data set of lab testing results (previously you all have been helpful but I have a new wrinkle). Each sample has 3 columns in excel(concentration, Qualifier, MDL) and Column A has about 167 chemicals that could possible be screened for. Not all samples were screened for all chemicals, so some of the samples may have blank rows. In column B is a benchmark value that the concentration should not be greater than. I need to do the following 3 things, which i think are somewhat related. 1) Count of samples tested for a chemical, 2) Count of samples with concentrations greater than benchmark with a qualifier <>"U", and 3) Count of samples with concentrations greater than benchmark with a qualifier ="U". See above for how the results should look.

Previously, I had used an aggregate function ([Suggested by you guys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36021926/conditional-max-min-on-horizontally-oriented-data?rq=1)) to get a max and minimum for samples with a qualifier of u and without - but i can't see a way to do a count using the aggregate function.

Comment: Can you post a picture of some sample spreadsheet values and an desired sample output?

Comment: I just updated it now; wasn't sure what worked best for people. Hope that helps.

Comment: In terms of seeing if a sample was tested for a chemical, if the concentration were blank, would that be s sufficient qualifier for a non tested sample or would conc, q and MDL all have to be blank?

Comment: I think that you are correct in assuming that if a concentration is blank, then so would the other information for a sample. Looks like your suggestion below takes that into account.

Comment: @Brian, you should mark the accepted answer from the referenced question as accepted if it suited your needs at the time.  Hit the check mark beside the answer that best suited.  Up and down triangles are for voting on the quality of the answer and are different from accepting the question.  Accepting the question will give you points which will eventually allow you do things on the site.

Comment: Just came back to see your edit, and that works much better. I believe i flagged it as answered now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you meant great than, and not great than or equal to your bench mark, the following three formulas should work for your sample data.  It is based on the assumption that a blank concentration means a sample was not tested.

The following counts non blank concentrations:

```
=SUM(--(F2<>""),--(I2<>""),--(L2<>""))
```

The following counts concentration greater than the bench mark and no U qualifier:

```
=SUM(--(AND(F2>B2,G2<>"U")),--(AND(I2>B2,J2<>"U")),--(AND(L2>B2,M2<>"U")))
```

The following counts concentrations greater than the bench mark and with a U qualifier:

```
=SUM(--(AND(F2>B2,G2="U")),--(AND(I2>B2,J2="U")),--(AND(L2>B2,M2="U")))
```

The above formulas are based on the chemical sitting in row 2.  copy down as needed.

Note the -- in the formula above simply change the TRUE or FALSE results to an integer 1 or 0 respectively.   This can also be achieved using any math operation that does not change the value such as *1 or +0.

## OPTION 2

### Counting With SUMPRODUCT

Again this will be on the assumption that if the concentration is empty/blank then no sample was tested for that row/chemical.  Since the need is to count instead of looking for a max and min, I am opting to use SUMPRODUCT.  Like AGGREGATE, it performs array like operations without actually being an array.

The following counts non blank concentrations:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($F$1:$N$1="Conc")*($F2:$N2<>""))
```

The following counts concentration greater than the bench mark and no U qualifier:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($F$1:$N$1="Conc")*($F2:$N2>$B2)*($G$1:$O$1="Q")*($G2:$O2<>"U"))
```

The following counts concentrations greater than the bench mark and with a U qualifier:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($F$1:$N$1="Conc")*($F2:$N2>$B2)*($G$1:$O$1="Q")*($G2:$O2="U"))
```

The above formulas are based on the chemical sitting in row 2.  copy down as needed.

Note the shift in range when checking for header Q and the value U

[image: POC]

Comment: So i see what you have done, and that works technically, but i was hoping that there would be a way to not have to hand code the cell references; to basically just say, look at the cells from Column F through Column XX you know? I say that, because we are importing more samples, and i would like to limit time in the future spent just manually entering cell references.

Comment: you can use aggregate like you did before, but since your headers do not match for your criteria on the left where you are also keeping the count, with the headers located in the sample, your formula will probably windup getting a lot bigger, and harder to understand in terms of formula maintenance.  Its not that it can't be done. As a follow up clarification, are you always just dealing with 3 samples?

Comment: Using an aggregate based solution would likely be ideal given how it looks like it scales up easily (given past experience generating max and min values. 

And no, i am dealing with many many more samples which is the problem. I am currently sitting at 200 samples, with potential to build onto that further

Comment: I just want to say thanks for that response. Took me a few tries to get it working - but that looks like it should work perfectly! And I came back just in time to use it. SumProduct is one of the tools i need to get better with, that is for sure. Can't thank you enough!


I'll be back on here if not! ha